# C# generic constraints for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics

```
public interface I {
}
public class A : I {
}
```

The compiler takes explicit `IEnumerable<A>` as `IEnumerable<I>` :

```
public void Test() {
    IEnumerable<A> a = new List<A>();
    new List<I>().AddRange(a);
}
```

But with generic constraints, we get:

```
public void Test<T>() where T : I {
    IEnumerable<T> t = new List<T>();
    new List<I>().AddRange(t);
}
                          ^^^
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IEnumerable<T>' to 'IEnumerable<I>'
```

However, this compiles fine.

```
public void Test<T>(T t) where T : I {
    new List<I>().Add(t);
}
```

Hence the question: is this a correct behavior, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that generic covariance only applies for reference types. For example, a `List<int>` is not* an `IEnumerable<Comparable>`, but a `List<string>` is.

So if you constrain `T` to be a reference type, it compiles:

```
public void Foo<T, I>() where T : class, I 
{
    IEnumerable<T> t = new List<T>();
    new List<I>().AddRange(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Covariance and Contravariance. Suffice to say it is not a bug, but a feature.

For an indepth look at this I recommend Eric Lippert's blog post series here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx